# How to share units between projects in the same project group?

Tags: delphi, ide

I am learning TDD in Delphi and I have a project group in which there are two projects: MyProject and MyProjectsTests. The last one will be responsible for the storage of all unit tests and it is using DUnitX's project template. Below is the current structure of my project group:

```
\MyProjectGroup
   \MyProject
      \Classes
         MyClass.pas
   \MyProjectTests
      \Tests
         MyClassTest.pas
```

In `MyClassTest` unit, how can I use `MyClass` unit from `MyProject`? While using CTRL+SHIFT+A hotkey, my IDE finds the unit and adds it to the uses clauses, but `MyProjectTests` won't compile and reports

> Unit 'MyClass' not found

Obviously I need to import it to MyProjectTests, but how?

Comment: Add the unit to your uses clause

Comment: No, @David. It's there, but cannot be found. It needs to be visible from (test) project's search path.

Comment: So add it to the project, or include its location in your search path

Comment: By adding to the project you simply mean right-click and "Add..."?

Comment: right click on  `\MyProjectTests` in your project root and click add, then add the unit

Comment: or if this a unit where you store utilities, and you would know that you will probably use it in your current and future projects then add this unit to the library search path

Comment: Project | Add from the menu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While adjusting the search path of MyProjectTests is a valid approach, I prefer to add the unit in question to the project directly. Either use the "Add Unit" command for that or simply drag'n'drop the unit from one project to the other.

Comment: Thank you Uwe, but could you explain more why you prefer adding the unit directly to the project instead of just using the search path?

Comment: @noen the more you limit the scope of things the safer you are

Comment: @noen, the compiler and the IDE (code insight) work more stable and faster when units are part of the project in contrast to units that can only be found in the search path. Another entry into the search path opens the whole folder to the compiler, which might not be what you want. Use the search path for common or third-party libraries, but add project specific units to the project.

Answer (score -4):

I don't advise sharing units between projects.

If multiple projects need to use the same unit, then put that unit in a third project. That third project should be a *package* project. Add that project's output directory to the library paths of the other two projects. They should now be able to use that unit as normal. You can choose whether you wish to build your other projects with run-time packages.

That third project should be the only project responsible for compiling that unit. To ensure that, don't allow the unit's directory to appear in the library path or search path of any other project. No other project should have access to the source code while compiling. (Go ahead and include the source directory in their *browsing* paths so that you can still Ctrl+Click or step through the source in the debugger.) Set the package's *output* directory to be distinct from the source directory, and then add that output directory to other projects' library paths.

Comment: I don't see how you can give this advise. Packages is one way to share code. But why is it better in all scenarios? I don't believe it is.  Packages create deployment headaches.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is right here. While packages may be a solution in some cases, these cases are only rarely found in real world scenarios. Using units in several projects of a project group is quite common and in most cases the preferred way to do so.

Comment: Packages are also a nightmare as the number of common units grows and you start to need multiple levels of included units.  Much simpler to keep your common library units separated.

Comment: It is better because including the source in multiple projects can provoke conflicting edits.

Comment: I didn't suggest _deploying_ a package, @David. That was explicitly _optional_: "You can choose whether you wish to build your other projects with run-time packages." I'm suggesting a package as an organizational tool that ensures that every unit is owned and compiled by exactly one project. When it's compiled by multiple projects, then it's not always clear whether a change to the file is meant for both projects. The behavior of a program might depend on which project was compiled more recently.

Comment: @Frogb, my suggestion _does_ "keep your common library units separated." They're in a _separate_ package — also known as a _library_ — instead of being shared among multiple projects, each of which _thinks_ it owns the units, but none of which actually do.

Comment: _Using_ units in multiple projects is exactly what I suggested, @Uwe. What I'm discouraging is _adding_ the unit to multiple projects. When you do that, then each project is prone to recompiling the unit, which leads to inconsistent builds.

Comment: One can make a change in a unit and mistakenly forget to re-build its common runtime package. That's what I was facing on daily basis in one company and it was hell. (no voting here)

Comment: @RobKennedy, you can avoid that with separate DCU paths for each project, platform and build configuration like _.\$(SanitizedProjectName)\$(Platform)\$(Config)_

Comment: That's how it should work. Packages are one way to structure code and should not be mixed up with package libraries. Just wanted to mention this explicitly.

Comment: I have a unit I share between most of my console apps. I see no need to put it in a package. I just add the directory with the unit [(Velthuis.AutoConsole)](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/autoconsole.html) in my Library path.

Comment: In many years of including the same unit in multiple projects, with different dcus output directory, I never encountered any of the problems that Rob alludes to.